# Suppose $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, with $a, b, c, d ∈ R$

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

Questions

> Find $a,b,c,d$ so the function $f$ is an even function.
> Find $a,b,c,d$ so the function $f$ is an odd function.

My understanding:

> Even function means $f(x) = f(-x)$.
> Odd function means $-f(x) = f(-x)$

We will have 2 equations, one for even function and the other for odd function:
$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = -ax^3+bx^2-cx+d$
$-(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) = -ax^3+bx^2-cx+d$

If I cancel out what I can I'll have:
$ax^3 + cx = -ax^3 - cx$ $<=>$ $2(ax^3+cx) = 0$ $<=>$  $ax^3+cx = 0$ $<=>$ $x*(ax^2+c)=0$
$-bx^2-d = bx^2 + d$ $<=>$ $bx^2+d = 0$

Should I not cancel? Any hints to how I should continue? First equation is basically $x = 0$ or $ax^2+c = 0$

Comment: Take $a=b=c=d=0$ for the first part.

Comment: You don't seem to be asked to find all $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ for these conditions. It might be enough to note that $f(x) = x$ is odd and $f(x) = 0$ is even. If you work out the more general algebra, polynomials with only even powers of $x$ will be even and polynomials with only odd powers of $x$ will be odd, and that might be the extent of it.

Comment: in fact, the zero function is also odd...

Comment: @hgmath I learn something new every day :). Thanks.

Comment: This is a valid approach.  You should think what it means for a polynomial to equal the zero polynomial, ie. Identically equal for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your reasoning is correct so far. In the even case, since $b$ and $d$ canceled out (thus they can actually be anything), you are only left with the equation you mentioned, $x(a x^2 + c) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ But this is obviously not true if $a$ and $c$ are not $0$, so we should in fact have $a = c = 0.$ Thus, the general solution for the first part is $f(x) = b x^2 + d.$ Doing the same for the odd case, we get the general solution $f(x) = a x^3 + cx.$

Comment: therefore the function is even for every b & d in the real number set as long as a & c are 0, and the function is odd for every a & c in the real number set as long as b & d are 0, right?

Comment: @cezar yes that's right

Comment: Exactly, in the first case $b, d \in \mathbb{R}, \, a = c = 0$ and in the second case $a, c \in \mathbb{R}, \, b = d = 0.$